# Unity 5 2d physics lags

Tags: android, unity3d-2dtools, unity-game-engine

I created a project(2D) with the last version of Unity. I added a tiny circle and attached a physics CircleCollider2D and RigidBody2D. When I launch the game I see little freezes when the ball is falling down. On Android I have the same. The profiler shows huge renderer load.
What to do with this poor performance?

Comment: Optimize rendering or the length of your draw call.

Comment: it would be impossible to help you unless you POST A LINK TO A ZIP FILE with the test project.  be sure you knwo what you're doing with relating to zipping Unity projects.  it's only the Assets/ and ProjectSettings/ folder and NOTHING ELSE

Comment: Try to change rigidbody2d->interpolate->none to interpolate.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ysSmCehZWSSko2Wi04NWFlVUE/view?usp=sharing

Here is the project

Comment: I tried with your project what juniperi suggested, and it works smooth now. Try interpolate all rigidbodies.

Comment: @juniperi make answer with it if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Rigidbody2d->interpolate->none to interpolate.

Quote from [Rigidbody2d.interpolation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-interpolation.html) documentation:

> Interpolation is used to estimate the position of the Rigidbody between physics updates. It can be useful to switch this on when the graphics update is much more frequent than the physics update because the object can appear to move along in jerky "hops" rather than having smooth motion.